# Load Byte[] Assembly into new AppDomain

Tags: c#, byte, appdomain

I currently get an assembly as a byte array from a remote stream. Is there anyway to load it the into a new AppDomain?

The AppDomain.Load(byte[]) does not work since it's giving me FileNotFoundException, I assume that the assembly must be on my computer.

```
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Assembly assembly = domain.Load(bytes);
            MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;
            if (method != null)
            {
                object o = assembly.CreateInstance(method.Name);
                try
                {
                    method.Invoke(o, null);
                }
                catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        });
        t.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass that byte array to code running in new AppDomain and call [Load(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7) on that data.

Now as with any loading of an assembly you need to understand how dependencies are resolved when useing different methods of loading assemblies. In most cases you'll have to either preload dependencies into new AppDomain or add AssemblyResolver event handler. Search for ["C# LoadFrom Cook"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+loadfrom+cook) to get to set of articles by  Suzanne Cook about loading assemblies.

Comment: What you are saying is that I should create a class or method that I would the above in the AppDomain? I will need to take a look at those articles.

Comment: Yes, you should load assembly from inside the domain you want it to be loaded to. Otherwise you'll be likely leaking classes out of that new AppDomain like you current sample does (it creates object which is made visible to parent domain). Side note: I assume that you understand that threads have nothing to do with AppDomains and code in any thread can cross AppDomain boundary many times.

Comment: The thread is a way to bypass an error (I am trying to run a WinForm within a WinForm), and I realize that the classes leaking. Much appreciated for the help.